# Warning C28251: Inconsistent annotation for 'WinMain': this instance has no annotations

Tags: c, winapi, warnings, compiler-warnings

I am getting a warning when compiling my code

```
Warning C28251: Inconsistent annotation for 'WinMain': this instance has no annotations.
```

This is my WinMain function

```c
int WinMain(HINSTANCE Instance, HINSTANCE PreviousInstance, PSTR CommandLine, INT CmdShow)
```

Comment: You can type the warning message into a search engine and fine lots of info. You really should be doing that first, and learning what you can, and trying to resolve the issue yourself. Only when you have exhausted that approach do you make a new question.

Comment: Grab the example of how WinMain should look like from Microsoft, not from some random web site.